# Model find subdocument array using user ID instead of [ [Object] ]

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

**Objective**
I'm trying to pull the qr documents attached to each user (which have a maximum of six) and return *both* the documents and subdocuments from the my mongoDB using below controller function.

**Function**

```
const Qr = require('../models/qr');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports.showActivations = async (req, res) => {
    const qrCodes = await Qr.find({ user: req.params.id });
    console.log(qrCodes);
};
```

**Expected results**
An example below shows how I expected the results to be returned by showing the subdocument details within 'redirect'

```
{
    _id: new ObjectId("6317ad944f0f1db567b9608c"),
    redirect: [ 
        name: "Test",
        url: "https://testurl.com"
        qrcode: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORwasdf..."
         ],
    user: new ObjectId("6310a2da50448e982336784a"),
    __v: 0
 }
```

**Actual behavior**
I am receiving `[ [Object] ]` instead of the redirect subdocuments with each document.

```
{
    _id: new ObjectId("6317ad944f0f1db567b9608c"),
    redirect: [ [Object] ],
    user: new ObjectId("6310a2da50448e982336784a"),
    __v: 0
 }
```

**qr.js (model)**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const qrSchema = new Schema({
    redirect: [{
        name: String,
        url: String,
        qrcode: String,
    }],
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    event: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Event'
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Qr', qrSchema);
```

How do I yield the full qr document and subdocument details from my query?

Comment: I don't see any obvious issues with the code... Could it just be the way console.log works? I know that it sometimes collapses actual objects into [Object] for simplicity. Have you tried directly accessing `qrCodes.redirect`, or `qrCodes.redirect[0]`? And what is the output?

Comment: Hey @MTN yes it looks like a version of that works. Great call. `console.log(qrCodes.redirect[0])` gives me `TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined` but `console.log(qrCodes[0])` gives me the full document & sub document so I should be able to iterate over it and save the array. Thank you for thinking of this approach.